# Cookies cannot read in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies

I created javascript cookie. But i can't read that cookie in wordpress. setcookie() function also not working. Only $_COOKIE is working .But it expiring in one minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following javascript function to **create**, **read** and **delete** cookies

**CREATE COOKIE**
`

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

`

**READ COOKIE**
`

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return decodeURIComponent(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
    }
    return null;
}
```

`

**DELETE COOKIE**
`

```
function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

`

Now, call javascript functions as:

```
createCookie('test','hello','5');
readCookie('test');
eraseCookie('test');
```

Comment: I used jquery for creating cookies. But the problem is, that cookies i can't read inside wordpress.

Comment: Can you please place your code javascript and php code for creating and reading cookies so that i can inspect in detail what's going on.

Comment: Solved the problem. I disabled varnish cache option in server. Now it is working fine.